# Remix error : Function declared as view but this (potentially) modifies state

Tags: crowdsale, upgrading, solidity-0.5.x

i'm following a tutorial but now it is old, because was written more then 1 year ago, with 0.4.24 pragma and i also want upgrade this code.
I got this error and i'm pretty sure to know why: view and pure cannot modify variables. 
But my question is: how do i must write this function to do it's job?

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";


contract IPPCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale {


    uint256 public investorMinCap = 100000000000000; 
    uint256 public investorMaxCap = 100000000000000000000; 
    mapping(address => uint256) public contributions;


    constructor (uint256 rate, address payable wallet, IERC20 token, uint256 cap, uint256 openingTime, uint256 closingTime)
    Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) 
    CappedCrowdsale(cap) 
    TimedCrowdsale(openingTime,closingTime)
    public
    {

    }

  function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary,uint256 weiAmount) internal view 
  {
    super._preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);
    uint256 _existingContribution = contributions[beneficiary];
    uint256 _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(weiAmount);
    require(_newContribution >= investorMinCap && _newContribution <= investorMaxCap);
    contributions[beneficiary] = _newContribution;
  }    



}
```

The function is the last one: _preValidatePurchase

Answer (score 1):

As you said view and pure function can't modify state so in order to update `contributions` you have to write another function.

Quoting comments Crowdsale.sol of  `_preValidatePurchase`

> @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met.
>        * Use `super` in contracts that inherit from Crowdsale to extend their validations.

this function is marked as view because it just performs checks not the state update.

I would do something like

```
function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary,uint256 weiAmount) internal view
  {
    super._preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);
    // custom validations here
  }    

function validPurchase (address beneficiary,uint256 weiAmount) public 
{
    _preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);
    uint256 _existingContribution = contributions[beneficiary];
    uint256 _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(weiAmount);
    require(_newContribution >= investorMinCap && _newContribution <= investorMaxCap);
    contributions[beneficiary] = _newContribution;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the example.
Could i ask why you made a public function (validPurchase)? Can i declare it as internal?
What i suppose to do is check if a contribution is more than MinCap and less then MaxCap.

Comment: I made it public for the example, you can make internal. In fact you may put the require(_newContribution >... ); inside _preValidatePurchase

Comment: I cannot put the require(_newContribution >... ); inside _preValidatePurchase because _newContribution is not declared yet... or am i wrong?